# Why can't I see my attachment page information for an image?

Tags: posts, images

I'm following a course where the tutor uploads an image to his media library. He adds attachment information. He then creates a new post and includes the image. When he clicks through, he gets the image with his attachment info below it.

I however do not. I click through and I just get the image by itself.

I'm sorry, I may be missing something obvious but I'm not sure what that is at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have selected `Media file` instead of `Attachment Page` in the `Attachment Display Settings`:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I went to Settings > Media but can't seem to find the drop-down you feature in your screengrab...

Comment: You could try to create a new post and insert an image via the "Add Media" button. Then this dropdown should become accessible in the Media popup.

Comment: Sorry but if I choose under the Media section, Add New, then it just gives an open space to drop a file or browse for them?

Comment: You will not find it under the  "Media" menu, you have to goto "Posts > Add new" and there you will see the "Add Media" button above the visual editor.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project.